# Spring Boot DevTools - RestartClassLoader problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

When using the spring boot dev tools library the are some problems with class loaders, mainly:
[image]

The problem is that there are two class loaders for dedicated class. When load the class from memcache and map/cast to object of class there is an exception like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class xxx.api.cache.CachedResponse cannot be cast to class xxx.api.cache.CachedResponse (xxx.api.cache.CachedResponse is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; xxx.api.cache.CachedResponse is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @2f6f8549)
```

I have tried to exclude `CachedResponse` class from restart or some how from `RestartClassLoader` but I did not manage to me.
I have used

```
restart.exclude.classes=file:/app/build/classes/java/main/
```

property but it exclude all classed in classpath. I have tried to exclude specific class `CachedResponse` but no results.
Also I have tried to include the folsom jar to `RestartClassLoader` but did not work.

Is there a possibility to exclude that `CachedResponse` class from `RestartClassLoader`?

Comment: I've seen this tool. I've disabled dev tools for now, but I'd love for my app to be compatible with dev tools.